# conditional row-wide replacement of values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe where all columns hold numeric data. How do I evaluate each row and in the case where **all** values in the row equal zero (i.e. when the rowsum = 0), replace those zeros with NA.

(If only some of the values in a row are zero I do not want to replace them)

Comment: Perfect - just what I wanted (but couldn't work out myself). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
d1[!rowSums(d1),]  <- NA
d1
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1   1  3  0  1  2
#2   1  2  3  1  2
#3   4  4  4  2  1
#4   3  4  0  0  1
#5  NA NA NA NA NA
#6   5  5  4  1  0
#7   1  1  0  4  2
#8  NA NA NA NA NA
#9   4  3  3  4  1
#10  1  0  0  5  2
```

Or

```
d1[!Reduce(`|`, d1),] <- NA
```

#### data

```
d1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 4, 3, 0, 5, 1, 0, 4, 1), V2 = c(3, 
2, 4, 4, 0, 5, 1, 0, 3, 0), V3 = c(0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 
0), V4 = c(1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 4, 5), V5 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```